# How do I dynamically populate a radio button using Jade/Pug

Tags: radio-button, pug

I am trying to dynamically populate the text in the radio buttons based on a list of email addresses stored in a variable named user.mail. However so far the best I've been able to get is a radio button with no text by doing the following:

```
dl
    dt Email Addresses
    dd
        ul#userEmailAddresses.list-unstyled
            li(ng-repeat='email in user.mail')
                input(type="radio", id="userEmailAddresses[email]", value="email", choose="email==user.rhatPreferredEmail")
```

I am very new to Jade and I understand that the version of Jade being used in my project isn't the latest (we haven't switched over to pug). Does anybody know if this is even possible to do?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to do this. Code should look like this:

```
dl
    dt Email Addresses
    dd#userEmailAddresses
        ul#radioEmailAddress.list-unstyled
            li(ng-repeat='email in user.mail')
                input#inputMail(type='radio', ng-model='$parent.email', ng-value='email')
                | {{email}}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Iteration

Here's an example from the docs of using [iteration / each](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

```
ul
  each val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    li= val
```

> *Note*: For `val` to be dynamically interpolated, you need to use `li= val` with an equals sign

#### Attributes

And here's an example from the docs of setting [attributes w/ interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation)

```
- var url = 'pug-test.html';
a(href= url) Link
```

> *Note*: For `url` to be dynamically interpolated, you need to use `(href= url)` without quotes

#### Code Sample

Putting that all together, we get the following code

```
each val in [1, 2, 3]
  label= val
    input(type="radio" value= val)
```

#### [Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/jOOPJex)